# Is 'that' necessary for this sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, sentence, syntactic-analysis

My friend and I were playing this game, in which we were complimenting others.

For example, she said, "You're so pretty, all the boys want to 'holla' at you."
Then I said, "You're so pretty, that all the girls just want to grab your face."

I was just wondering if 'that' is necessary for this type of context, and is it formal to add the 'that?' If so, is a comma needed before 'that'? Please explain!

Comment: Given the type of question you’ve asked, I think you might be interested in [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). ELL tends to be a better fit for these sorts of questions than ELU does.

Answer (score 3):

In speech, *that* is not necessary. If you’re recording direct speech, then you write what the speaker actually said, and, in your example, a comma would not be required.

If you’re writing a similar sentence yourself, rather than recording what someone else said, then add *that*.

Comment: I would strongly disagree with a comma after *that*, as   I believe that the comma replaces *that* in informal speech. (You wouldn't put a comma after *that* in my last sentence, presumably?)

Comment: @TimLymington. You're right. Answer amended.